# Cannot reboot/shutdown Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I hadn't any problem with 14.04, but 16.04 is so buggy. I can't reboot Ubuntu after installation is completed from live USB/DVD and I must press the power button. Also `sudo reboot` and `sudo poweroff` don't work when Ubuntu is booted. I updated Ubuntu but the problem still exists.

Comment: Is there any error shown when you try `sudo reboot`?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo shutdown -r -f now` instead of reboot?

Comment: Did you do a direct upgrade to 16.04?  I found issues when I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, I just saved my data off, and did a fresh install of 16.04.  in my 21 years of computer experience, direct upgrades are too dirty, and have issues (Good luck all those that upgrade Windows 8 to 10, :-)), but apparently we here in the Linux world have some of the same issues.  If this was s direct install and you cleaned the harddrive, then let me know, and I will try to research for you.

Comment: @ryandoherty No. Just Ubuntu gets stuck in purple screen with loading bar.

Comment: @Azulflame Doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram I wiped my SSD and did a fresh install.

Comment: Can you tell us what hardware you are running it on?  Perhaps this has something to do with the hardware.  I know it seems like we may be stabbing in the dark, but in trouble- shooting sometimes the most basic stuff is where you start.... Is it plugged in, is it turned on... LOL

Comment: Sorry, what make and model is the computer.

Comment: @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram OK. [This is my PC](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/VivoBook-Pro-N552VW). Thanks for your efforts ;)

Comment: OK, I looked up the Linux laptop hardware support site, and do not see your laptop.  This can be a bad thing, but not always.  It seems your laptop is kind of a gaming laptop, so I am thinking the issue is unsupported hardware.  What you might try doing is updating the kernel to one of the latest.  4.5.4 is available, and now 4.6.0.  Normally I would not tell you to do this, and just follow the upgrades to the kernel as they come, but some of these issues may be addressed in a newer kernel you can find them here as well as instructions http://www.yourownlinux.com/

Comment: Only thing is follow the instructions for the correct OS bit version if you install 32bit kernel on 64bit machine you will get a kernel panic, and will need to revert back to a working kernel from grub.  Just so you know how to get to grub JIC when you boot your machine, hold down the shift key and grub will eventually come up.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram. I think the problem is because of `acpi` and GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The first problem (reboot problem after installation was completed) occurred because I set `acpi=off` during the installation because Ubuntu got stuck in loading purple screen. After many tries I could pass by the purple screen by chance without setting `acpi=off`! Then after installation, Ubuntu was restarted without any problem.

The second problem (shutdown and restart problem after Ubuntu was booted for the first time from hard disk) was because of Nvidia driver. I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

And now everything is fine :-)

**UPDATE**

As I said I could not pass by the purple screen during the installation and I found what the problem was. I had connected a USB 2.0 flash drive to a USB 3.0 port for installing Ubuntu. Today I connected a USB 3.0 flash drive to the USB 3.0 port and I booted Ubuntu with that and the problem was solved (I don't need to wait for a chance or set `acpi=off` to boot Ubuntu). But unfortunately I am getting a new problem and it is I cannot reboot or shutdown Ubuntu .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Asus Vivobook n552vw laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual-booting in UEFI mode.

Finally I found that Secure Boot was disabled in my UEFI settings. Enabling Secure Boot fixed the issue for me.