# Asus N552VW ubuntu install error

Tags: boot

I am not be able to install ubuntu on Asus B552VW.
I tried every method. I disabled secure boot, booting with nomodeset but it didnt work. What is the prooblem? Is there anybody solve this problem and help? This is really frustrating.

Comment: I have got the same Laptop as you have. I think it's a BIOS or driver problem. See [Cannot reboot/shutdown Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/777383/255257).

Comment: So did you solve eventually?

Comment: Yes an No! I wanted to figure out what the problem was. So I tried many times to boot Ubuntu without changing any default settings. You can simply use `acpi=off` during installation but after installation when Ubuntu is restarting you have to press power button.

Comment: Actually ı had succeed to install by only doing secure boot disabled. After that ı tried to restart and i met a frozen screeing and uninstall ubuntu tried again but i never could install after that time. This is really comedy. I tried acpi=off but with nomodeset not only. I am gonna try like you. I didnt get when ubuntu restarting you have to press power event. What if i dont catch? :))

Comment: Can you somehow mount the root partition, and then get to the grub configuration file in /boot/grub and remove a "quiet" parameter for the kernel so you can see what is going on as it tried to boot?

Somehow you need to figure out what part of the boot process is not working: bios/eufi, then grub, then kernel, then init...  There are many good pages on this on the web so I won't got into it in detail.

And first you need to figure out if your box boots w/ bios or eufi.

Comment: After installation Ubuntu asks for restarting the system, but when you press restart button Ubuntu gets stuck and doesn't restart. So you have to press your physical power button on your laptop to restart/shutdown the system. Also before installing reset your BIOS to its default.

Comment: I had restarted by clicking not manually. Damn it!

Comment: If it restarted without any problem, so why you complain about it! :D

Comment: I mean i just click the restart. :)) But the result is not successfull.

Comment: Also I think there is a way to change the kernel parameters more simply, using grub.  You might want to browse the grub manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/index.html#Top

Comment: Be aware that `acpi=off` is a big and sometimes even dangerous hammer and can affect a lot more than just whether the reset button works. On one laptop I had, it meant that the fans would _never spin up_, causing overheating very quickly.

Comment: Yes. But in my case it doesnt stop and this means too much noise.

Comment: Too much running of my fan means overheating of pc because of ubuntu.