# New Dell - Ubuntu/Fedora won't boot usb

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb, virtualbox, fedora

**My device**

i bought i new Notebook (Dell Inspiron 15-7559) few months ago.

Specs:

- i7-6700hq and 120gb SSD + 1TB HDD
- nvidia geforce gtx 980
- 4k resolution and 16GB ram

**What i want**

Now i want to leave windows 10 and go linux (I have some experience with ubuntu and never had problems installing it on other pcs).

**What i have tried**

I tried to format USB with different LiveUSB Creator softwares. I tried to iso images from ubuntu, kubuntu and fedora on my usb stick (64GB Sandisk). But not a single linux distro worked.

Ubuntu: The graphical loading screen just freezes..i do not even get to the point of choosing to "try" or to "install" ubuntu.
Fedora: 
-> 1. The command line loading screen freezes at "makin user manager 1000" or something like that
-> 2. When i press to "check this media" it tells me "it is not recommended to use this media"

Virtualbox:

- Fedora installation and booting works in VirtualBox (exact same iso as i used to brun onto my usd device)
- Ubuntu installation works in VirtualBox (same iso)

So what could be the problem? Should i buy a new usb stick? Is the hardware/Bios or something to new for linux and the hardware is not supported yet..is something like that possible?

EDIT:
I deactivated all "secure boot options and keys" and then the installation kind of worked. Then Ubuntu asked to reboot itself. Now the installed ubuntu freezes just the same way as it did before installing.

Comment: See [Asus N552VW ubuntu install error](http://askubuntu.com/q/818262/255257) and [Cannot reboot/shutdown Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/811222/255257).

Comment: Can you try the [Fedora 25 alpha](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/prerelease/)? It has a very recent kernel (4.8.0 rc2) and may have better hardware support.

Comment: Also, can you try the [new Fedora Media Writer](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB#Using_Fedora_Media_Writer_.28Windows_and_Fedora.2C_graphical.2C_destructive.29) to create your USB stick? This may eliminate the "not recommend" problem.

Comment: Thank you mattdm.
Fedora was installed. But at the login screen it freezes and hangs.

I tried to install ubuntu with "nomodeset" before the installation by pressing "e" before that. Thank kind of worked, but the installation process crashed afterwords.

I think i'll have to wait until the Linux Distro get used to this bug/hardware and try again later.